# How to make a copy of a custom object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, object, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I made a custom object that inherits from NSObject. Let's say I have an array of these objects. Then I want to make another object, that is a copy of one of the objects in the array. I do not want to simply point to an existing object in the array I want a copy. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `NSCopying` [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) on the object, and use it as follows:

```
MyFoo * theCopy = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] copy];
```

Note that `theCopy` is a retained object at this point, and should be released when you are done with it.